# Двухсторонее связывание в angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Есть обьект в котором собираються данные из view , далее я хочу передавать эти данные в различные функции , но когда я делаю так как описано ниже , обьект по умолчанию не two way binding , и приходиться использовать watch , если ли другой способ , и вариации реализации такого же поведения.

```
   var defaultOption = {
            some: $ctrl.option1,
            some2: $ctrl.option2
        }

        $scope.$watchGroup(['$ctrl.option1','$ctrl.option2'],myFunc);

        function myFunc() {
            defaultOption = {
                some: $ctrl.option1,
                some2: $ctrl.option2
            }
        }

// Затем я вызываю нужные функции
myFunc1(defaultOption)
myFunc2(defaultOption)
...
```

Проблема в том что данные там не коректные

Comment: а ты точно хочешь менять опции по умолчанию?

Comment: это для примера названы обьекты , я хочу менять обьект который будут потом бросать в функции

Comment: попробуй в вопросе подробнее расписать пример использования

Comment: @Grundy Описал более подробно

Comment: в этом случае - никак. Внутри функций, параметр всегда будет ссылаться на старую переменную, так как ты меняешь целиком объект. кстати не понял, почему этот объект не поместить в контроллер и не связывать именно его?

Comment: На самом деле прост не надо было менять ссылка ну объект `defaultOption = {...}` - надо было просто обновить нужные свойства этого объекта. Еще возможно проблема с тем когда вызываются функции `myFunc1` и `myFunc2`